# How to make fields editable?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a website where I enter some information which is stored in SQL server. I want to make my fields editable. Can someone help me to make them editable?

This is how the first page looks like where I enter my information in fields about the user:

[image: here i enter information into fields]

In this picture is the final view which is saved:

[image: its final version stored in sql]

This is code of the first page:

```html
@model UserManagement.damateba

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        @Html.ActionLink("User Management", "UserManagement", null, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
        <a href="http://localhost:59320/Home/" class="navbar-brand" style="margin-left:850px;"> გამოსვლა </a>
    </div>
</div>
<br />

<br />
<br />
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>სახელი:</td>
        <td>@Model.Name</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>გვარი:</td>
        <td>@Model.Surename</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>მეილი:</td>
        <td>@Model.Email</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ნომერი:</td>
        <td>@Model.Phone</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>სქესი:</td>
        <td>@Model.Gender</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>თარიღი:</td>
        <td>@Model.DateOfBirth</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>CV:</td>
        <td>
            @{
                if (Model.CVname != null)
                {
                    if (Model.CVname != "")
                    {
                        @Html.ActionLink(Model.CVname, "Download", new { id = Model.id })
                    }
                }
            }
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>სხვა:</td>
        <td>
            @{
                if (Model.Othername != null)
                {
                    if (Model.Othername != "")
                    {
                        @Html.ActionLink(Model.Othername, "Download", new { id = Model.id })
                    }
                }
            }
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>PI:</td>
        <td>@Model.PI</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>PI კოდი:</td>
        <td>@Model.PICode</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>LI ქულა:</td>
        <td>@Model.LiScore</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>LI ჯამური:</td>
        <td>@Model.LiTotal</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>სხვა ტესტი 1:</td>
        <td>@Model.OtherTest1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>სხვა ტესტი 2:</td>
        <td>@Model.OtherTest2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>პოზიცია:</td>
        <td>@Model.Position</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>კატეგორია:</td>
        <td>@Model.Kategoria</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>ქვეკატეგორია:</td>
        <td>@Model.Qvekategoria</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>კომენტარი:</td>
        <td>@Model.Comment</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br />
<br />


<button class="btn" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Usermanagement", "Home")';return false;"> <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i> უკან</button>
<button class="btn" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Delete", "Home", new { id = Model.id })';return false;"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i> წაშლა</button>
```

This is the code of the second page:

```html
@model UserManagement.Models.AddUserModel

<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            @Html.ActionLink("User Management", "UserManagement", null, new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
            <a href="http://localhost:59320/Home/" class="navbar-brand" style="margin-left:850px;"> გამოსვლა </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br />



    @using(Html.BeginForm("Adduser", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype="multipart/form-data"}))
    {

        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>სახელი:</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>გვარი:</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Surename)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>მეილი:</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>ნომერი:</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Phone)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>სქესი:</td>
                <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Gender, new List<SelectListItem>
               {
                   new SelectListItem {Text = "მამრობითი", Value="მამრობითი", Selected=true},
                   new SelectListItem {Text ="მდედრობითი", Value="მდედრობითი"},
               })
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>კატეგორია:</td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DropDownList("Kategoria", new List<SelectListItem>
               {
                   new SelectListItem{ Text="საპორტო ოპერაციები", Value="საპორტო ოპერაციები", Selected= true},
                   new SelectListItem{ Text="საინფორმაციო ტექნოლოგიები", Value="საინფორმაციო ტექნოლოგიები"},
                   new SelectListItem{ Text="ტექმომსახურება", Value="ტექმომსახურება"},
                   new SelectListItem{ Text="საზღვაო მომსახურებები", Value="საზღვაო მომსახურებები"},
                   new SelectListItem{ Text="ადამიანური რესურსების მართვა", Value="ადამიანური რესურსების მართვა"},
                   new SelectListItem{ Text="კომუნიკაცია", Value="კომუნიკაცია"},
                   new SelectListItem{ Text="ფინანსები", Value="ფინანსები"},
                   new SelectListItem{ Text="რისკები და შესაბამისობა", Value="რისკები და შესაბამისობა"},
                   new SelectListItem{ Text="იურიდიული მხარდაჭერა", Value="იურიდიული მხარდაჭერა"},
                   new SelectListItem{ Text="შესყიდვები", Value="შესყიდვები"},
                   new SelectListItem{ Text="საწყობი და სამეურნეო ლოგისტიკა", Value="საწყობი და სამეურნეო ლოგისტიკა"},
                   new SelectListItem{ Text="ადმინისტრაცია", Value="ადმინისტრაცია"},
                   new SelectListItem{ Text="კომერციული", Value="კომერციული"},
                   new SelectListItem{ Text="შრომის და ზოგადი უსაფრთხოების, ჯანმრთელობის და გარემოს დაცვა", Value="შრომის და ზოგადი უსაფრთხოების, ჯანმრთელობის და გარემოს დაცვა"},
                   new SelectListItem{ Text="პროცესების განვითარება და სრულყოფა", Value="პროცესების განვითარება და სრულყოფა"}
               }, new { style="width=175px;"})
                </td>
            </tr>
                        <tr>
                <td>ქვეკატეგორია:</td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DropDownList("Qvekategoria", new List<SelectListItem>
               {
                   new SelectListItem {Text="ოპერაციების მართვა", Value="ოპერაციების მართვა", Selected=true},
                   new SelectListItem {Text="ოპერაციების დაგეგმვა", Value="ოპერაციების დაგეგმვა"},
                   new SelectListItem {Text="საპორტო ტექნიკის მართვა", Value="საპორტო ტექნიკის მართვა"},
                   new SelectListItem {Text="ტრანსპორტი / დისპეტჩირება", Value="ტრანსპორტი / დისპეტჩირება"},
                   new SelectListItem {Text="გამშვები პუნქტი / ტალმანირება", Value="გამშვები პუნქტი / ტალმანირება"},
                   new SelectListItem {Text="სადოკერო / დამხმარე საქმე", Value="სადოკერო / დამხმარე საქმე"},
                   new SelectListItem {Text="საბორნე ოპერაციები", Value="საბორნე ოპერაციები"},
                   new SelectListItem {Text="ნავთობტერმინალი", Value="ნავთობტერმინალი"}
               }, new { style="width=175px;"})
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>თარიღი:</td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m=>m.Year, new List<SelectListItem>
               {
                        new SelectListItem {Text = "2018", Value = "2018"},
                        new SelectListItem {Text = "2019", Value = "2019", Selected = true},
                        new SelectListItem {Text = "2020", Value = "2020"},
                        new SelectListItem {Text = "2021", Value = "2021"},
               })

                    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Month, new List<SelectListItem>
               {
                        new SelectListItem {Text = "იანვარი", Value="1", Selected = true},
                        new SelectListItem {Text = "თებერვალი", Value="2"},
                        new SelectListItem {Text = "მარტი", Value="3"},
                        new SelectListItem {Text = "აპრილი", Value="4"},
                        new SelectListItem {Text = "მაისი", Value="5"},
                        new SelectListItem {Text = "ივნისი", Value="6"},
                        new SelectListItem {Text = "ივლისი", Value="7"},
                        new SelectListItem {Text = "აგვისტო", Value="8"},
                        new SelectListItem {Text = "სექტემბერი", Value="9"},
                        new SelectListItem {Text = "ოქრომბერი", Value="10"},
                        new SelectListItem {Text = "ნოემბერი", Value="11"},
                        new SelectListItem {Text = "დეკემბერი", Value="12"},
               })
                    @Html.DropDownList("Day", new List<SelectListItem>
                   {
                       new SelectListItem { Text = "1", Value = "1", Selected= true},
                       new SelectListItem { Text = "2", Value = "2"},
                       new SelectListItem { Text = "3", Value =  "3"},
                       new SelectListItem { Text = "4", Value =  "4"},
                       new SelectListItem { Text = "5", Value =  "5"},
                       new SelectListItem { Text = "6", Value =  "6"},
                       new SelectListItem { Text = "7", Value =  "7"},
                       new SelectListItem { Text = "8", Value =  "8"},
                       new SelectListItem { Text = "9", Value =  "9"},
                       new SelectListItem { Text = "10", Value =  "10"},
                       new SelectListItem { Text = "11", Value =  "11"},
                       new SelectListItem { Text = "12", Value =  "12"},
                       new SelectListItem { Text = "13", Value =  "13"},
                       new SelectListItem { Text = "14", Value =  "14"},
                       new SelectListItem { Text = "15", Value =  "15"},
                       new SelectListItem { Text = "16", Value =  "16"},
                       new SelectListItem { Text = "17", Value =  "17"},
                       new SelectListItem { Text = "18", Value =  "18"},
                       new SelectListItem { Text = "19", Value =  "19"},
                       new SelectListItem { Text = "20", Value =  "20"},
                       new SelectListItem { Text = "21", Value =  "21"},
                       new SelectListItem { Text = "22", Value =  "22"},
                       new SelectListItem { Text = "23", Value =  "23"},
                       new SelectListItem { Text = "24", Value =  "24"},
                       new SelectListItem { Text = "25", Value =  "25"},
                       new SelectListItem { Text = "26", Value =  "26"},
                       new SelectListItem { Text = "27", Value =  "27"},
                       new SelectListItem { Text = "28", Value =  "28"},
                       new SelectListItem { Text = "29", Value =  "29"},
                       new SelectListItem { Text = "30", Value =  "30"},
                       new SelectListItem { Text = "31", Value =  "31"}
                   })
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>CV:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="file" name="file1" id="file1" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>სხვა:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="file" name="file2" id="fil2" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>PI:</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PI)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>PI კოდი:</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PICode)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>LI ქულა:</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LiScore)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>LI ჯამური:</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.LiTotal)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>სხვა ტესტი 1:</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.OtherTest1)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>სხვა ტესტი 2:</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.OtherTest2)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>პოზიცია:</td>
                <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Position)</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>კომენტარი:</td>
                <td>@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Comment)</td>
            </tr>
        </table>

        <button type="submit" class="btn"> <i class="fa fa-save"></i> შენახვა</button>
        <button style="margin-left:20px;" class="btn" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Usermanagement", "Home")';return false;"> <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i> უკან</button>
    }
</body>
</html>

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#Month").change(function () {
            var day = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "Post",
                url: "/Home/GetSelectList?days=" + day,
                contentType: "html",
                success: function (response) {
                    $("#Day").empty();
                    $("#Day").append(response);
                }
            })
        })
        $("#Kategoria").change(function () {
            var kate = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                type: "Post",
                url: "/Home/GetSelectCategory?Categor=" + kate,
                contentType: "html",
                success: function (response) {
                    $("#Qvekategoria").empty();
                    $("#Qvekategoria").append(response);
                }
            })
        })
    })
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean make your fields editable? What issue are you trying to over come?

Comment: The "second page" looks like the user can edit the fields and submit the form

Comment: I have fields and I can submit them only once then I cant change them , I want to add the edit  function to all fields to correct them.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you could use your second form and make in editable. So only use second form with disabled properties and then enable on button click. 
So you can do it this way:

```
    <script>
        //First disable form according to some parameter
        $(document).ready(function () {
           disableForm();
        });

        //Load this on your document ready
        function disableForm()
        {
           //your submit button class
           $('.btn').attr('disabled', true);
           //your form tag
           $('.form').(':input:not(:disabled)').prop('disabled', true);
        }

        //Load this on your document ready
        function enableForm()
        {
           //your submit button class disable
           $('.btn').attr('disabled', false);
           //your form tag
           $('.form').(':input:not(:disabled)').prop('disabled', false);
        }

        //Enable button where you enable all 
//inputs on your form and enable your Submit button so you can submit your changes
        $("#enableButton").click(function() {
          enableForm()
        });

    </script>
```